# Error LNK2019 Directx10 VC++2010

Tags: visual-c++, directx-10

I am trying to learn about DirectX 2010, after setting up the Libraries
how i installed the Libraries:-
VC++ 2010-View-other windows-Property manager

i opened the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user
VC++ Directories :-
   Include Directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include
   Library Directories: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x64

here is the  Error list i get:-
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateEffectFromFileW@48 referenced in function "long __cdecl InitDevice(void)" (?InitDevice@@YAJXZ)   c:\Users\ahmed_saad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CodeName_Yarab\CodeName_Yarab\Main.obj    CodeName_Yarab
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@32 referenced in function "long __cdecl InitDevice(void)" (?InitDevice@@YAJXZ) c:\Users\ahmed_saad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CodeName_Yarab\CodeName_Yarab\Main.obj    CodeName_Yarab
Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   c:\users\ahmed_saad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CodeName_Yarab\Debug\CodeName_Yarab.exe   1   1   CodeName_Yarab

i am using Windows 8 pro x64

Comment: Add "d3dx10.lib" to the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.

Comment: I did that and thats the new output
1>------ Build started: Project: CodeName_Yarab, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateEffectFromFileW@48 referenced in function "long __cdecl InitDevice(void)" (?InitDevice@@YAJXZ)
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@32 referenced in function "long __cdecl InitDevice(void)" (?InitDevice@@YAJXZ)
1>C:\Users\Ahmed_Saad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CodeName_Yarab\Debug\CodeName_Yarab.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you'll need to link to a .lib-file, because DX ist not among the usual libraries.
Look for a .lib file and add it to your Linker properties.

Comment: i tried linking them one by one i mean like adding d3dx10.lib and then adding d3d10.lib but nothing happens

Comment: oh by the way, how to add libs on there own, i used the Linker/input method is there another one?

Comment: Depends on the libraries (dll or lib). But the usual way is through the linker-options in VS. Or by adding it to your sources in the solution-explorer (mostly .lib) or dlls via LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress-Functions